# looping content of a file to arguments

Tags: bash, file, loops, arguments, sh

So you all know this right? 
[Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

So what I want to do is loop the contents of a file to arguments. Which change outputs etc

#### What I tried:

```
while read $1 & $2 & $3; do
#also tried:
#while read $1 $2 $3; do
    echo ${1}
    echo ${2}
    echo ${3}

    ./${1}.sh & ./${2}.sh & ./${3}.sh

done <file.txt
```

#### Results in:

```
#arguments aren't echoed
./script.sh: line 31: ./.sh: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 31: ./.sh: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 31: ./.sh: No such file or directory
#scripts aren't executed
```

#### file.txt contents

```
apple_fruit
#$1
apple_veggie
#$2
veggie_fruit
#$3
pear_fruit
#$1
pear_veggie
#$2
veggie_fruit
#$3
```

This loops like this, in this pattern ^^

#### I've also tried changing the file to this:

```
apple_fruit apple_veggie veggie_fruit
pear_fruit pear_veggie veggie_fruit
```

#### In a nutshell:

I want $1 to be replaced by apple_fruit, $2 to be replaced by apple_veggie, and $3 to be replaced by veggie_fruit. Then when it hits `done` I want it to replace $1 with pear_fruit, $2 with pear_veggie, and so on.

#### Related Mini-Questions

And also, to get this to work, do you add no argument when you're entering this script

```
script.sh
```

or do you actually have to put something in, if you do what? Because the argument is always going to be changing.

```
script.sh mystery mystery mystery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three lines, three `read`s:

```
while IFS= read -r l1
      IFS= read -r l2
      IFS= read -r l3
do
    echo "$l1, $l2, and $l3"
done <<EOF
apple_fruit
apple_veggie
veggie_fruit
pear_fruit
pear_veggie
veggie_fruit
EOF
```

The output is

```
apple_fruit, apple_veggie, and veggie_fruit
pear_fruit, pear_veggie, and veggie_fruit
```

There's no real reason to involve the positional parameters here; just use regular variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash `readarray` builtin to read lines into an array (`line`):

```
readarray line < file.txt
echo ${line[@]}
```

output:

```
apple_fruit                                                              
apple_veggie                                                             
veggie_fruit                                                             
pear_fruit                                                               
pear_veggie                                                              
veggie_fruit
```

Then you could do

```
printf './%s.sh & '  "${line[@]}" | sed 's/ \& $//'
```

which outputs

```
./apple_fruit.sh & ./apple_veggie.sh & ./veggie_fruit.sh & ./pear_fruit.sh & ./pear_veggie.sh & ./veggie_fruit.sh
```